# How to add javascript to be executed after all page is charged and extensions dynamic elements are added

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a website running with Wordpress and using some extensions and plugins. 
There is a button added through an extension, and I try to get this element with getElementById in javascript code added in the header of the page. But even inside a document.onload, the getElementById returns null.
I guess that's because the element is added dynamically after the page is loaded and even after the document.onload statment.
How could I manage to get the element in javascript?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use a timer for this.

```
var myTimeInterval = setInterval(function() {
    var el = document.getElementById("element");
    if (el) {
        // Your code here
        clearInterval(myTimeInterval);
    }
}, 1000);
```

This one will check every second whether #element exists or not, if it exists, perform your actions and remove the timer, if not, skip to the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Try window.onload

http://javascript.tutorialhorizon.com/2016/03/17/window-onload-vs-document-onload/

A dirty solution may be to set a timeout before you try to select the element to give it time to load.